# Learning parameters of noise and filter coefficients from data where data and noise both have Gaussian distributions

Tags: statistics, error-estimation

Assume $X$ and $N$ are two sets of vectors (observations) from a normal distribution, where $X$ represents clean data and $N$ represents noise; and $A$ a projection matrix of a filter. The scenario is that our clean data was corrupted by a multiplicative noise via matrix $A$ and an additive noise of $N$:

$$Y=A X + N.$$

How can we learn the projection matrix $A$ and $N$ from the training data $X,Y$? Does the Gaussian assumption of $A$, $N$ and $X$ help to have a better estimation or guide to use a specific solution?

Here is matlab code for the training data, noise and a simple projection:

```
    dataVariance = .10;
    noiseVariance = .05;  
    mixtureCenters=randn(13,1);
    X=randn(13, 1000)*sqrt(dataVariance ) + repmat(mixtureCenters,1,1000);

    %N and A are unknown and we want to estimate them.
    N=randn(13, 1000)*sqrt(noiseVariance ) + repmat(mixtureCenters,1,1000);
    A=2*eye(13);

    Y=A*X+N;

    for iter=1:1000
        A_hat,N_hat = training(X_hat,X,Y);
    end
```

---

Note: if necessary, for each estimation of $A$, an error can be calculated for an estimation of $N$ using a current $A$.

For example:

```
for iterate=1:1000
  initiate A
  estimate N using current A (N=Y-A*X)
  calculate error of estimation (err=Y-A*X+N)
  update A
```

But I would prefer not to go for gradient descent approaches.

Comment: Look up multivariate linear regression. One way would be learning each row of $A$ separately using classical linear regression.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what about $N$? I need to learn both.

Comment: After learning $A$, you have samples of the noise, and then you can estimate its parameters statistically.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I see. Is this ok to forget about the additive noise $N$ while estimating via multivariate linear regression and estimate $A$ without considering $N$?

Comment: Multivariate linear regression takes the noise into account. If there was no noise, you could find $A$ by solving linear equations. In fact, since your noise is Gaussian, you should use a min least squares method.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus so by using mvlr, I learn $A$, then get examples of $N$ for the current estimation of $A$. Now I have an estimation of $N$ and $A$. Can I use these estimations to calculate estimation error of $Y$ and improve my estimations iteratively?

Comment: Probably, though you'll have to ask somebody else for the details.

Comment: [Also posted on Scicomp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/21892/4274).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that of *multivariate linear regression*. Finding each row of $A$ corresponds to a classical *linear regression* problem, which can be solved using the method of least squares, which is optimal here since the noise is Gaussian.

Once you have an estimate for $A$, you can estimate the parameters of $N$ by isolating $N = Y-AX$. (This is not necessarily the optimal method since you only have an estimate for $A$, but practically it might be good enough.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize the answers given for this question, here I provide a visualization of different methods carried out to learn the projection matrix $A$ given clean samples $X_i$ and noisy samples $Y_i$:

[image: learning the projection matrix using different methods: first row: original matrix for 5 different cases, second row: initialization of the matrix, third row: using normal equation, directly derive the projection matrix, fourth row: linear regression using gradient descent and finally, fifth row, using kalman filtering]

In the first row we can see 5 different projection matrices ($A$) chosen to project $X$ before adding Gaussian noise $N$.

In the second row, you can find the random projections initialized to be learned via different methods.

In the  third row, using the normal equation, we directly derive the projection matrix:
$$ \hat A = (X^T \times X)^{-1} \times X^T \times Y$$

In the fourth row, a linear regression using gradient descent is used to learn the projections via $X$ and $Y$.

And finally, the last row, using kalman filtering method (find out more about it [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21892/learning-parameters-of-noise-and-filter-coefficients-from-data-where-data-and-no/21936?noredirect=1#comment35807_21936)).

As you can observe, the GD solution and the normal equation are very similar and since in this example, $(X^T \times X)^{-1}$ is feasible to calculate, it sounds a more reasonable solution and can be done in only one step. If the dimensionality of our features were too high, then we can use the GD since both $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian.

The KF solution converges faster than GD, but can not achieve a good performance as GD, I believe.

After learning $A$, $N$ can be calculated via: $$\hat N=Y- \hat A \times X$$

and further $\hat {\mu_N}$ and $\hat {\Sigma_N}$ can be computed using $\hat N$.

Comment: This answer was copy-pasted on [on SciComp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/21892/4274) too.